# How can I avoid this Deadlock in Oracle.sql.ARRAY type?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, deadlock

We've come across the deadlock situation below when running multiple Java EE MDB instances that are trying to write to the DB:

```
[deadlocked thread] [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)':
Thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'' is waiting to acquire lock 'oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@90106ee' that is held by thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)''

Stack trace:
oracle.sql.ARRAY.toBytes(ARRAY.java:673)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setArrayCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5985)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setARRAYInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5944)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8782)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8278)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8868)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:240)
weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:287)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:356)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:127)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.setValues(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:298)
org.springframework.jdbc.object.BatchSqlUpdate$1.setValues(BatchSqlUpdate.java:192)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:892)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:586)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:614)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:883)
org.springframework.jdbc.object.BatchSqlUpdate.flush(BatchSqlUpdate.java:184)
com.csfb.fao.rds.rfi.common.dao.storedprocs.SaveEarlyExceptionBatchStoredProc.execute(SaveEarlyExceptionBatchStoredProc.java:93)
com.csfb.fao.rds.rfi.common.dao.EarlyExceptionDAOImpl.saveEarlyExceptionBatch(EarlyExceptionDAOImpl.java:34)
com.csfb.fao.rds.rfi.application.rulesengine.RulesEngine.saveEarlyExceptions(RulesEngine.java:302)
com.csfb.fao.rds.rfi.application.rulesengine.RulesEngine.executeRules(RulesEngine.java:209)
com.csfb.fao.rds.rfi.application.rulesengine.RulesEngine.onMessage(RulesEngine.java:97)
com.csfb.fao.rds.feeds.process.BaseWorkerMDB.onMessage(BaseWorkerMDB.java:518)
weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:466)
weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:371)
weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:327)
weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4547)
weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4233)
weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:3709)
weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:114)
weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5058)
weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

and...

```
[deadlocked thread] [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)':
Thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'' is waiting to acquire lock 'oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@b48b568' that is held by thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)''

Stack trace:
oracle.sql.ARRAY.toBytes(ARRAY.java:673)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setArrayCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5985)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setARRAYInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5944)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8782)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8278)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8868)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:240)
weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:287)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:356)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:127)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.setValues(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:298)
org.springframework.jdbc.object.BatchSqlUpdate$1.setValues(BatchSqlUpdate.java:192)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:892)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:586)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:614)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:883)
org.springframework.jdbc.object.BatchSqlUpdate.flush(BatchSqlUpdate.java:184)
com.csfb.fao.rds.rfi.common.dao.storedprocs.SaveEarlyExceptionBatchStoredProc.execute(SaveEarlyExceptionBatchStoredProc.java:93)
com.csfb.fao.rds.rfi.common.dao.EarlyExceptionDAOImpl.saveEarlyExceptionBatch(EarlyExceptionDAOImpl.java:34)
com.csfb.fao.rds.rfi.application.rulesengine.RulesEngine.saveEarlyExceptions(RulesEngine.java:302)
com.csfb.fao.rds.rfi.application.rulesengine.RulesEngine.executeRules(RulesEngine.java:209)
com.csfb.fao.rds.rfi.application.rulesengine.RulesEngine.onMessage(RulesEngine.java:97)
com.csfb.fao.rds.feeds.process.BaseWorkerMDB.onMessage(BaseWorkerMDB.java:518)
weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:466)
weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:371)
weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:327)
weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4547)
weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4233)
weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:3709)
weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:114)
weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5058)
weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Looking at the ARRAY.toBytes() method:

```
  public byte[] toBytes()
    throws SQLException
  {
    synchronized (getInternalConnection())
    {
      return this.descriptor.toBytes(this, this.enableBuffering);
    }
  }
```

..., it synchronizes on the following method (getInternalConnection() -> getPhysicalConnection()):

```
  oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection getPhysicalConnection()
  {
    if (this.physicalConnection == null)
    {
      try
      {
        this.physicalConnection = ((oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection)new OracleDriver().defaultConnection());
      }
      catch (SQLException localSQLException)
      {
      }

    }

    return this.physicalConnection;
  }
```

defaultConnection() does the following:

```
  public Connection defaultConnection()
    throws SQLException
  {
    if ((defaultConn == null) || (defaultConn.isClosed()))
    {
      synchronized (OracleDriver.class)
      {
        if ((defaultConn == null) || (defaultConn.isClosed()))
        {
          defaultConn = connect("jdbc:oracle:kprb:", new Properties());
        }
      }
    }

    return defaultConn;
  }
```

So there's synchronizations on the connection instance and OracleDriver.class object... I can't see how this can deadlock. To get to the point of needing the lock on OracleDriver.class, the thread would already have the lock on the connection instance.... clearly I'm missing something.

We are creating the ARRAY type using the following code:

```
public ARRAY getOracleLongArray(DataSource ds, List<Long> vals, String typeName)
        throws SQLException {
    oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection conn = (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) ds
            .getConnection();
    Object[] data = vals.toArray(new Object[0]);

    ARRAY mddArray = conn.createARRAY(typeName, data);
    conn.close(); // Close the extra connection made here.
    return mddArray;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you check to see what .getConnection() calls under the covers?

Comment: getConnection() just returns the connection from the DataSource. We're running this in weblogic so it gets a connection from the pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are sharing that connection with multiple threads (by way of that `defaultConnection()` method. Don't do that, make sure a connection is used by only one thread at a time.

Comment: The issue is more that the ARRAY instance opens and maintains a db connection. We're doing this in Weblogic so are using a connection pool. This runs out of connections very quickly.

Comment: AFAIK you need to create that ARRAY on the same connection that will use it.

Comment: Thats was it Mark - thanks.  We were using a Connection pool but passing DataSources - every time we created a New ARRAY object it was getting a different Connection object and thus creating a new db connection.

Answer (score 1):

Mark had the answer:
We were using a Connection pool but passing the DataSource reference to it - every time we created a New ARRAY object it was getting a different Connection object from the Datasource (to that used by the actual db call) and thus creating a new db connection.

We wrapped the DataSource to always return the same connection and it fixed the issue.

Thanks